# How to chain-install the Kinect Runtime with my executable?

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have developed a WPF application which used the Kinect. Now I'm trying to export my application to an installer and I'd like to include the Runtime in it. The point would be that the user would only have to launch the installer once and it will first install the Runtime and then my application. How can I do that?

I have read the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855357.aspx which says " a Kinect-enabled application setup program should chain-install the Kinect Runtime Setup." but I don't know how to achieve that...

Thanks by advance,
Valentin

Comment: What kind of installer project you're using? Each one has its own syntax (Visual Studio Installer, WiX, InstallShield...) to add prerequisites

Comment: I have tried with the Visual Studio Installer. I wanted to try InstallShield but I couldn't download it as the website was down...

Comment: With Visual Studio Installer simply add a custom action to run Kinect installer on Commit (if that installer isn't listed in available prerequisites in the "Prerequisites" dialog inside project properties).

Comment: No it isn't listed in the "Prerequisites"... I'm sorry but I'm just starting with Visual studio and I don't understand what you mean by "simply add a custom action on Commit"... Can you detail please?

Comment: Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.80).aspx check paragraph about "To add the custom action"

Comment: Thanks for the link but I finally manage to use Installshield and it seems easier. I can now include the Kienct Runtime but I still cannot start the installation from my installation...

Comment: It's the same thing...use a custom action! http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q102426

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this, is by using the Windows Installer XML toolset (WiX) (http://wixtoolset.org/).

It provides a way to build package bundles to include several .msi files, which will be installed one after the other (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/).